# Outer Joining SQL Tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have three table in the Database -

1. Activity table with activity_id, activity_type
2. Category table with category_id, category_name
3. Link table with mapping between activity_id and category_id

I need to write a select statement to get the following data:

```
activity_id, activity_type, Category_name.
```

The issue is some of the  activity_id have no entry in the link table.

If I write:

```
select a.activity_id, a.activity_type, c.category_name 
from activity a, category c, link l 
where a.activity_id = l.activity_id and c.category_id = l.category_id
```

then I do not get the data for the activity_ids that are not present in the link table.
I need to get data for all the activities with empty or null value as category_name for those not having any linking for category_id.

Please help me with it.

PS. I am using MS SQL Server DB

Comment: Don't use those old-style implicit `JOIN`s!  **EVER!**

Comment: then any other solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` for your activity table to return all rows.

```
SELECT
a.activity_id, a.activity_type, c.category_name 
FROM activity a
LEFT OUTER JOIN link l 
ON a.activity_id = l.activity_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN category c
ON c.category_id = l.category_id;
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use proper explicit joins:

```
select a.activity_id, a.activity_type, c.category_name 
from activity a
LEFT JOIN link l 
ON a.activity_id = l.activity_id 
LEFT JOIN category c
ON l.category_id = c.category_id
```

Answer (score 1):

If writing this type of logic will be part of your ongoing responsibilities, I would strongly suggest that you do some research on joins, including the interactions between joins and where clauses.  Joins and where clauses combine to form the backbone of query writing, regardless of the technology used to retrieve the data.

Most critical join information to understand:

- Left Outer Join: retrieves all information from the 'left' table and any records that exist in the joined table
- Inner Join: retrieves only records that exist in both tables
- Where clauses: used to limit data, regardless of inner or outer join definitions.

In the example you posted, the where clause is limiting your overall data to rows that exist in all 3 tables.  Replacing the where clause with appropriate join logic will do the trick:

```
select a.activity_id, a.activity_type, c.category_name 
from activity a 
     left outer join link l --return all activity rows regardless of whether the link exists 
          on a.activity_id = l.activity_id
left outer join category c --return all activity rows regardless of whether the link exists  
          on c.category_id = l.category_id
```

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

What about?

```
 select a.activity_id, a.activity_type, c.category_name  from category c
 left join link l on c.category_id = l.category_id
 left join activity a on l.activity_id = a.activity_id
```

Actually, the first join seems that it could be an `inner join`, because you didn't mention that there might be some missing elements there